# Having error while declaring binding variable in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Hi I am getting the error, need advise. The code is:

```
VARIABLE v_bind1 VARCHAR2(10); --declare bind variable

exec : v_bind1 := 'RebellionRider'; --execute it

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

BEGIN

dbms_output.put_line(v_bind1);

END;
```

It prints the below output when m trying to declare the variable:

```
Usage: VAR[IABLE] [ <variable> [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) |
    VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) |
    NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | BLOB | BFILE
    REFCURSOR | BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ]
```

and when tried to print it, it shows below error:

```
SP2-0552: Bind variable "V_BIND1" not declared.
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the colon character. I think the line should be: `exec v_bind1 := 'RebellionRider';` Also the value that you are assigning to the variable is more than ten characters.

Comment: after posting question i kinda debeugged it. 
     thanks for your comment though. yes thats the error and working code is as below
     VARIABLE v_bind1 VARCHAR2(30);
     SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
     BEGIN
     :v_bind1:='testing';
     dbms_output.put_line(:v_bind1);
     END;
/
print :v_bind1;

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the : right next to the bind name:

```
VARIABLE v_bind1 VARCHAR2(10); --declare bind variable

exec :v_bind1 := 'RebellionRider'; --execute it
```

and then reference it as `:v_bind1`.

[For reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/sqlplus.816/a75664/ch34.htm):

> You reference bind variables in PL/SQL by typing a colon (:) followed
> immediately by the name of the variable. For example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is SQL*Plus and not PL/SQL Developer as the error you posted is a SQL*Plus error, it's because of the trailing comment:

Fails:

```
SQL> VARIABLE v_bind1 VARCHAR2(10); --declare bind variable

Usage: VAR[IABLE] [ <variable> [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) |
                    VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) |
                    NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | BLOB | BFILE
                    REFCURSOR | BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ]
```

Succeeds:

```
SQL> VARIABLE v_bind1 VARCHAR2(10);
SQL>
```

The SQL terminator character (by default it's `;` but don't forget it's [configurable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-5D91A9A9-13A2-4F62-B02A-AD2F3AFF8BB7)) must appear at the end of the line, otherwise SQL*Plus won't recognise it. But SQL*Plus commands like `variable` don't need a SQL terminator and don't have any comment syntax anyway, so the whole line is rejected as invalid.

The next issue you had was that `v_bind1` and `:v_bind1` are two different things. This fails because `v_bind1` is an undeclared PL/SQL local variable (it would have needed to be declared within the block):

```
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(v_bind1);
end;
/
```

What you needed was the bind variable you just declared named `:v_bind1`:

```
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(:v_bind1);
end;
/
```

As `v_` and `:` both indicate a variable, I'd suggest you don't need the first one.